# data.sort is undefined or data.sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am showing JSON data in a table form on HTML page, i want to sort the data on button click by alphabetical order (title). After clicking a button i got an error that data.sort is undefined or data.sort is not a function. The page does not need to be reloaded for sorting function. I am deleting the head of the code to make it shorter

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <h1>TOP MOVIES</h1>
            <button id="btn-sort">Sort</button>
            <br />
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="movie_table">
              <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>IMDB-ID</th>
                <th>RANK</th>
                <th>RATING</th>
                <th>RATING-COUNT</th>

                      </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>

      </body>
    </html>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5dc2e815c9b247772abb67b2/1", function(data) {
        var movie_data = '';
        $.each(data.movies, function(key, value) {
          movie_data += '<tr>';
          movie_data += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
          movie_data += '<td>' + value['imdb-id'] + '</td>';
          movie_data += '<td>' + value.rank + '</td>';
          movie_data += '<td>' + value.rating + '</td>';
          movie_data += '<td>' + value['rating-count'] + '</td>';
          movie_data += '<tr>';
        });
        $('#movie_table').append(movie_data);
      });

      $("#btn-sort").click(function(data) {
        data.sort(function(a,b) {
          return a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
        });
        var movie_data = '';
        $.each(data.movies, function(key, value) {
          movie_data += '<tr>';
          movie_data += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
          movie_data += '<td>' + value['imdb-id'] + '</td>';
          movie_data += '<td>' + value.rank + '</td>';
          movie_data += '<td>' + value.rating + '</td>';
          movie_data += '<td>' + value['rating-count'] + '</td>';
          movie_data += '<tr>';
        });
        $('#movie_table').slice(1).remove(); // To remove everything except first row
        $('#movie_table').append(movie_data);
      });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Function event click returns an event as param not the data that you want to sort, your click function will returns an event object, take a look the click event in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Comment: You need a global variable (not the best practice) and store the data returned from $.getJSON. Then use the variable to sort. The data in your click event is not the same data as in ajax block. Their name is same, hence the confusion, but the scope is different.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do to your code.

For example:

1) Add `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to your HTML table so that you only need to update the body when the data changes.

2) Use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to load the data. That way you can maintain a global data store easily.

3) [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) over your dataset and return a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) of your row data.

4) Add functions for reusable code.

```js
// Add `async` to the enclosing function
$(document).ready(async function() {

  const endpoint = 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5dc2e815c9b247772abb67b2/1';

  // Await your data. `getJSON` is a promise-like structure so you can use `await` on it
  // We can destructure out the movies property from the data
  const { movies } = await $.getJSON(endpoint);

  // Because you're reusing some code you can put it in a function and call it
  // with a new set of data each time
  function getTableHTML(movies) {

    // `map` will return a new array so make sure you
    // `join` it up at the end to make one complete HTML string
    return $.map(movies, function(movie, index) {
      return `
        <tr>
        <td>${movie.title}</td>
        <td>${movie['imdb-id']}</td>
        <td>${movie.rank}</td>
        <td>${movie.rating}</td>
        <td>${movie['rating-count']}</td>
        </tr>
      `
    }).join('');
  }      
  
  // Get the movie HTML
  const tableHTML = getTableHTML(movies);

  // Add it to the movies table body
  $('#movie_table tbody').html(tableHTML);

  // I've separate out the sort function
  function sortMovies(movies) {
    return movies.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
    });
  }

  $("#btn-sort").click(function(data) {

    // Now you simply need to pass in the movies
    const sortedMovies = sortMovies(movies);

    // And pass the sorted movies into your getTableHTML function
    const tableHTML = getTableHTML(sortedMovies);

    // Then update the table body again
    $('#movie_table tbody').html(tableHTML);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1>TOP MOVIES</h1>
    <button id="btn-sort">Sort</button>
    <br />
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="movie_table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>IMDB-ID</th>
        <th>RANK</th>
        <th>RATING</th>
        <th>RATING-COUNT</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```